# Python 3.9+ multiprocessing in a class function within custom module

Tags: python, pandas, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

While Python documentation is full of details about multiprocessing
and https://zetcode.com/python/multiprocessing/ provides interesting explanation,
I can't run successfully any of the example without running into errors.
Even Python's own examples give:

> AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'f' on <module '**main**'  (built-in)>

My main goal is to be able to load multiple compressed pickle files containing parts of a pandas dataframe into the memory and join them, or directly join them into one dataframe.
The data is quite big for my machine, so I need to store it compressed (hence Dask isn't even an option).

Any working ideas are welcome.
My Python version is 3.9.7, Pandas 1.3.4

[update]
an example of this can be found here:
https://www.journaldev.com/15631/python-multiprocessing-example
which has the code:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
def print_func(continent='Asia'):
    print('The name of continent is : ', continent)

if __name__ == "__main__":  # confirms that the code is under main function
    names = ['America', 'Europe', 'Africa']
    procs = []
    proc = Process(target=print_func)  # instantiating without any argument
    procs.append(proc)
    proc.start()

    # instantiating process with arguments
    for name in names:
        # print(name)
        proc = Process(target=print_func, args=(name,))
        procs.append(proc)
        proc.start()

    # complete the processes
    for proc in procs:
        proc.join()
```

and the same error occurs upon running on clear console

Comment: /usr/bin/python may be an old version of Python on your computer.  Try running `/user/bin/python --version` to see which version  it is.  You may have to modify the #! line.

Comment: I'm on Windows. No such address.

Comment: Then I think we're going to need more precise information on what exactly it is you're running (there are multiple examples on that page) and what error message you're getting, complete with a stack trace.

Comment: I'm saying that I can't even run official examples, so any example that actually works, will be useful. Just have multiple files (output of pandas.to_pickle(filename, compression='bz2'), and try to read them in parallel. 
The fact is, I am trying to build a whole class, to optimize my data performance, with one function (method) in this class reading files in parallel.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit the question to include a [*"Minimal, Reproducible, Example."*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: If you're using jupyter: don't. Multiprocessing is difficult to get working in an interactive session on windows. Jupyter is always an interactive session. Instead use an editor where you create an entire ".py" file and execute it.

Comment: Which operating system? How are you running this code? It works when run as a script. It may not work when run in some sort of shell environment, especially in Windows where a new python process is executed (as opposed to forked like on linux).

Comment: I use Spyder. Great debugging capabilities. :) 64-bit OS

Comment: @tdelaney Win10 x64, Python is 3.9.7, Spyder is 5.1.5. I don't see this clearly stated in the documentation. I think something significant changed in 3.8.

Comment: I agree that its not obvious what the problems are. On windows, `multiprocessing` will execute a new python.exe. It will then try to import your script. The parent side will pickle its state, send it to the child and the child will unpickle it. This often doesn't work in a shell / interactive environment where you don't have a top level script to import.

Comment: Alternately, you can write separate script that does your multiprocessing stuff and use `subprocess.run` to run it. There are other solutions too, but its a bit much to put in a comment.

Comment: oh my! Very useful description, thx! Aren't there any wrappers? E.g. how sklearn enables njobs>1 and other libs like numpy allow multiple computations at once?

Comment: @Julian they have their own multiprocessing code written in c and fortran which is separate from python's multiprocessing

Comment: Just confirming the example written in the question does not run with python 3.9.7 on spyder 5.1.5 on Windows 10 OS? I cannot reproduce any error on a similar setup. What is the error you get? In the example code there is no `f` function or variable, so that error must be from a different script.

Comment: This is the setup, yes. And the error is the same: AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'f' on <module 'main' (built-in)>

and I assume this has something to do with Spyder being an IPython (interactive console) IDE